# Alternatives to using a Collection class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception, collections

I have been looking through old code to get familiar with the system I use and found a piece of code that I feel can be used better.

What goes on here is some data gets added to the collection(around 150 string variables, some with two variables(variableName/VariableValue), most with only one(VariableName)).  It will try to set a module level string variable to the item of the collection passing it the index(variableName) then if there's a value setting the VariableVAlue to the module level variable.

What I feel needs work is that if the collection is passed a variable and the variable doesn't have a value it will return a "" which would cause a runtime error hence there's a On Error GoTo Handler code to manually add a "" to the collection.  I feel there's a better way to do this rather than knowing there will be a runtime issue then solving it after catching it.  Would there be a way to have a return "" not throw an exception or would the use of an Array also work here since it's a "collection" as well?

Here's an example to try to help visualize:

```
Public Function  GetCollectionVariable(ByVal varName as string) as String
If collection1 Is Nothing Then
        m_collection1 = New Collection 
    End If
On Error GoTo Handler
GetCollectionVariable = collection1.Item(VarName)
exit function

Handler:
collection1.add("", VarName)
GetCollectionVariable = ""
End FUnction
```

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Which type is collection1?

Comment: The collection is declared as dim collection1 As Collection

Comment: Collection is not a concrete type, is your code creating the collection? Which concrete type you create?

Answer (score 2):

If `Collection1` is a dictionary, you can use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).